# Fonts not working when loaded by css modules

Tags: css, webpack, font-face, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm using css modules with sass. So i try to load them like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
  src: url(@/assets/fonts/book_antiqua.ttf) format('truetype');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  src: url(@/assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

[The most interesting path is that they actually loaded by the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAmt3.png)

So inline css looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
  src: url("http://localhost:8080/static/media/book_antiqua.d8ae129c.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal; }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  src: url("http://localhost:8080/static/media/Montserrat-Regular.2bb14503.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal; }
```

But they do not work( So i understand nothing. Browser loaded fonts, font-face syntax looks OK, but they do not trigger.

My webpack config's loaders:

```
rules: [
      {
        exclude: [
          /\.html$/,
          /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
          /\.css$/,
          /\.json$/,
          /\.bmp$/,
          /\.gif$/,
          /\.jpe?g$/,
          /\.png$/,
          /\.scss$/,
        ],
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
        options: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
            'postcss-loader',
          ],
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                modules: true,
                sourceMap: true,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
            'sass-loader',
          ],
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
          },
        },
      },
    }]
```

Comment: Update: the actual reason is that instead of real fonts file loader outputs something with 300 bytes sizes. Definitely not real fonts , but corrupted ones.

Answer (score 0):

I never import fonts from my assets, I always use services like google fonts to get mine, they have [montserrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat) there and I import it like this

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
```

But that's just a band-aid, another place were a problem could be found is where do you use that font, how do you add that font to a certain class is important, for example for montserrat you should do it like this

```css
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
```